# Unknown column 'siteurl' in 'where clause' WPDB outside

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to get Mysql values from outside wp.
My code:

```
define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

$wpdb->get_var("SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = siteurl");
```

What i missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option_name is type VARCHAR, iow. a string

Try:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'");
```

Comment: yeah it worked like a charm!

Comment: Then please accept the answer - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer